# Which vertical bar scales properly?

Tags: vertical-alignment, size

I sometimes need to write expressions which include derivatives evaluated at a certain point (for example, a Taylor series). My preferred notation (see addendum) is as in the first equation of the MWE below.

Now, one of my pet peeves is setting font sizes (or any other sizes, for that matter) by hand in LaTeX. I am currently using `\bigg|`, but that won't work anymore if the function and/or the variable becomes bigger, and I really don't want to set all the sizes by hand on all my equations (I have quite a few instances of derivatives evaluated at specific points in different chapters of my document, and each chapter is in its own .tex file). I've tried `\vrule`, but this resulted in an undesirable vertical positioning of the subscript (see MWE below). Is there a command that produces a vertical bar which scales to the height of whatever it is adjacent to *and* positions subscripts appropriately?

MWE (some of the packages might be unnecessary; sorry about that):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\der}[2]{\frac{\text{d}{#1}}{\text{d}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\dder}[3]{\frac{\text{d}^{#1}{#2}}{\text{d}{#3}^{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent This looks nice:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) & = & \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}\,\dder{k}{f}{x}\bigg|_{x=x_0}
\end{eqnarray}
But this doesn't:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) & = & \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}\,\dder{k}{f}{x}\vrule_{x=x_0}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image: First equation has a \bigg|, second one has a \vrule.]

As an addendum, I do appreciate conciseness in a document, but I value clarity as well. I'm reluctant to use `f'` to denote `df/dx` or `\partial f/\partial x` because f may be a function of many variables (as in the case with the `\partial`s). I'm also reluctant to use `f_x` to denote `df/dx` because I often use subscripts to tell apart different contributions to (or components of) a quantity. Therefore, I don't want to write `f^{(k)}(x_0)` or other such things. This is non-negotiable; I'd rather not have answers like "change your notation", please. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: addressing just the vertical bar, `\vrule` is never correct here.  if you don't want to set the size by hand, then put `\left.` just after the sum component, and `\right|` or `\right\rvert` between the end of the evaluated expression and the "subscript".  that will usually result in something reasonable, although a manual selection can often be more precise.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yet, one thing you should change is`\eqnarray` in favour of `align`: your spacing around `=` is much too large. In addition, the syntax will be simpler.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, `\left. maths go here \right|` works! I can't believe I didn't think of that before; I use `\left(` and `\right)` all the time. :)

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the welcome! I actually like the extra space around the =, as it increases the readability of the equation. If you have a polynomial sort of thing (i.e. many terms on one or both sides of the equation separated by minus and/or plus signs), it can be a little difficult to tell where the left side ends and the right side begins if the space around the = is the same as that around the minus and plus signs, don't you think?

Comment: I don't think there's a real chance  for this, as generally there are several `=` signs vertically aligned.

Comment: the default space around = (which is also used by `align` is larger than the space around + and - (relations get `\thickmuskip` binary operators get `\medmuskip` The spacing for `eqalign` is based on that of `tabular` and is basically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose two solutions: an `\eval` macro, with two arguments, which is adapted from a code found on this site – I don't remember where, and a different version with the starred version of `\diff`, from package `esdiff`. Note the same package has handy `\diffp` and its starred version for partial derivatives.

I also replaced `eqnarray` with `align` for a better horizontal spacing around the alignment point. Also note you don't have to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{esvect, esdiff}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\eval#1#2{\mathchoice
              {\setbox0\hbox{${\displaystyle #1}_{\scriptstyle #2}$}
              \evalaux{#1}{#2}}
              {\setbox0\hbox{${\textstyle #1}_{\scriptstyle #2}$}
              \evalaux{#1}{#2}}
              {\setbox0\hbox{${\scriptstyle #1}_{\scriptscriptstyle #2}$}
              \evalaux{#1}{#2}}
              {\setbox0\hbox{${\scriptscriptstyle #1}_{\scriptscriptstyle #2}$}
              \evalaux{#1}{#2}}}
\def\evalaux#1#2{{#1\,{\vrule height .67\ht0 depth 1.2\dp0}_{\,#2}} }

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f(x) & =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}\,\eval{\diff[k]{f}{x}}{x=x_0}\\[1ex]
f(x) & =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}\diff*[k]{f}{x}{x = x_0}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: should use box0 not box1 for local assignments

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks. It's an old code I have, and I didn't know that. I've fixed it. As I'm curious: what is the reason for that?

Comment: convention of plaintex and latex as documented in texbook, registers 0-9 are scratch registers with odd numbered ones for global and even numbered ones for local assignments. If you don't follow the convention you may get an unexpected nested global assignment changing things and you can generate excessive save stack use due to the way tex copes with local and global assignments to the same register

Comment: others may disagree, but the vertical bar looks too short at the top.  the usual appearance is for the vertical bar to be symmetrical about the math axis.  see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/983398/233629 for an example.

Comment: @barbara beeton: It was purposely, to make a difference between the vertical bar used for definite integrals – difference (!) of values  of the anti-derivative at the bounds of the interval of integration, and the vertical bar  used for evaluating a function at some point, or restricting it to a subdomain. It also shows one can play with height and depth of the vertical rule, contrary to an approach base on, say, tabular. That said, perhaps I'm too much of a nitpicker.

Comment: i'm afraid the subtlety was lost on me.  thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the elegant solution. I like the idea of defining an `\eval` operation to evaluate something at a specific point. However, I agree with @barbarabeeton concerning the shortness of the bar; I'd say the lack of a superscript here (as opposed to when the bar for definite integrals is used) eliminates all possibility of confusion. I'll take a hybrid approach and use barbara's idea of `\left.` and `\right|` together with your idea of defining an `\eval` operation.

Comment: By the way, I've compared `\diff` from the `esdiff` package and my own `\dder` operation and they look identical, so rather than loading a whole new package I'll stick to my four lines of code defining first-order and higher-order normal and partial derivatives. :)

Comment: In my code, you just have to replace `height 0.67\ht0` with  `height 1\ht0` or something like that. If you take `0.75`  you almost have the golden ratio  for height/depth.  For this example, your code indeed yields a similar result to esdiff's. If you take a look at thhe (short) documentation, you'll see there are options for the spacing between the differential symbols and the function. Also it has a simplified management of crossed partial derivatives, calculating the order of derivation from the exponents of the variables.

Comment: I'll be sure to give that a read, since crossed partial derivatives do indeed give me trouble with my current system. Thanks again!